# How to make a select with 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 tables: tbImages, tbUsers

tbImages has lots of paths of images with unique ids
tbUsers has lots of users with unique ids...

I will code a page that make a delivery of images...This page will show all images ordering by id... The admin will select 7 images to send it to some user by email... I will have to register when and how many times some user has received that image (a 3rd table maybe)...
Here is the problem... I'll have  to ORDER images by date of register.. Images already sent have to appear at end of that delivery page...

What is the better way to do this?  tbImages has lots of columns one for each user? A 3rd table (tbDelivered) one row each user with column 'images received'? ?How to make this SELECT to show already sent images at end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3rd table relating your `imageID` to a userID (relational table).  Then you can use `JOIN` statements in your query.  For example:

```
relational_table
  imageID
  userID
  sendCount
```

Query could be:

```
SELECT sendCount
FROM relational_table
WHERE imageID = $imageID
AND userID = $userID
```

That would give you back the number of times that image has been sent to that user.

Comment: Right... so how is this select? may you describe? Im noobie with join statemens

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a 3rd table that will contain:

- The image ID
- The user ID
- The quantity

And you will make a select statement that will look like this:

```
SELECT tbImages.imageID, tbDelivered.quantity
FROM tbImages, tbDelivered
WHERE tbImages.imageID = tbDelivered.imageID;
```

To show the ones that have not already been delivered you will have to add at the end of it:

```
AND quantity = 0;
```

I hope this helps